# Unable to install magento on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, magento, ubuntu, installation

Recently i changed my system in that i'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

I installed PHP5, Apache2, mysql, Curl.

I installed all the required softwares for Magento But when i'm trying to install it its showing **Not Found**

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

The latest version (EE 1.14.0.1 and CE 1.9) will run on PHP 5.5.9. I haven't experienced issues yet in my testing.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1.7 only runs on Apache 2.2 and more important PHP 5.4. Ubuntu Server 14.04 contains Apache 2.4.7 and PHP 5.5.9. Partially magento will run on this setup (mine instance does), but very buggy.

Also i think your problem may be a wrong configured virtual host, deny/allow directives are changed since Apache 2.4. Take a look at your apache log files for more detailed information.